# How to config intellij to make '{}' has space, eg: 'import {combineReducers} from 'redux' to become import { combineReducers } from 'redux

Tags: reactjs, import

How do I config intellij to make '{}' have space, eg:
 'import {combineReducers} from 'redux' to become import { combineReducers } from 'redux

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Live Template for your import statements. Go to **Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> Live Templates**, and you can use their templating language to structure how you'd like your import statements to be formatted. For more information, you can check out [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-templates-2.html).

Comment: I want to use command+alt +L or command+alt +O  to make the "import {match, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';" become the "import {  match, NavLink   } from 'react-router-dom'".{}has whitespace

Comment: Just to clarify, are you intending on writing your import statements without surrounding white space in the braces, and then using a keybinding to quickly fix your code? Because it would be much faster to define a Live Template or a custom Code Construct that already has the import statement defined with white space, and the cursor automatically moves to the center for you to define the object(s) to be imported, and afterwards will automatically move the cursor to within the quotes so you can define the library.